# Upload/Encode files via REST API

Tags: node.js, azure-media-services, azure-rest-api

I can't seem to find any documentation for uploading and encoding on the microsoft docs for AMS. All I see is live stuff. I do see this on the dotnet SDK, but not for node.js, so I'm trying to find something using the REST API. Does anyone have any microsoft docs or tutorials for uploading and encoding Azure Media Services v3 using the REST API?

Thanks for any help (I'm a newbie here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For REST see the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-rest
For Node.js see the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-nodejs-quickstart

Answer (score 0):

We are adding more and more Node.js content now that the newer Typescript SDK is out there.
Keep an eye on samples here.

I built a simple upload and encode sample here.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/tree/main/AMSv3Samples/StreamFilesSample

Let me know if that gets you started and if that is enough information to understand the basics.

I would avoid trying to roll your own REST based SDK client, since there is very helpful retry logic built into the official NOde.js/TypeScript SDK for Media Services.

Comment: Thanks for that specific file, that really helped.